# Ansible password_hash with variable

Tags: ansible

I am writing a simple task to create a user. As part of this task, I want to read the password from defaults/main.yml

**`defaults/main.yml`**

```yaml
test_user: testuser
test_group: testgroup
test_user_password: somepassword
```

**my tasks file is as below**

```yaml
- name: "Creating Group for testuser"
  group:
    name: "{{ test_group }}"
    state: present

- name: "Creating testuser"
  user:
    name: "{{ test_user }}"
    password: "{{ [test_user_password] | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    shell: /bin/ksh
    group: "{{ test_group }}"
    update_password: on_create
```

This gives me a unexpected templating error. How can I read the password from `main.yml` and use it inside the password filter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Creating testuser task remove the square brackets around test_user_password. When a variable is referenced in Ansible it has to be enclosed with {{}}.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: user
  become: yes

  vars:
    test_user: testuser
    test_group: testgroup
    test_user_password: somepassword

  tasks:
    - name: Creating Group for testuser
      group:
         name: "{{ test_group }}"
         state: present

    - name: Creating testuser
      user:
         name: "{{ test_user }}"
         password: "{{ test_user_password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
         shell: /bin/bash
         group: "{{ test_group }}"
         update_password: on_create
```

Comment: How to use a variable instead `test_user_password` in the role?
`password: "{{ '{{test_user_password}}' | password_hash('sha512') }}"` this doesn;t work for me, but I found somewhere this should work...

Comment: test_user_password is a variable already. In the answer above it is set to somepassword

Answer (score 7):

Take into account that given task will always be marked as "changed" meaning that it is not idempotent. To avoid this behaviour you can add salt as a second parameter to password_hash function, like this:

```yaml
- name: Creating testuser
  user:
     name: "{{ test_user }}"
     password: "{{ test_user_password | password_hash('sha512', test_user_salt) }}"
     shell: /bin/bash
     group: "{{ test_group }}"
     update_password: on_create
```